# Removing and re-adding ssh keys doesnt change the email associated?

Tags: ssh, email

This seems like maybe a bug? I've changed my email in GitHub to use the noreply form that is more private. I tried changing the email in the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file and using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, but it says my old email. I've only adding this key (with no other key on this machine) today. So I tried using `ssh-add -d ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to delete the the keys and add again, and also manually deleted them, and checked both the known_hosts and authorized_keys files and deleted known_hosts.old file, but still the old email. Tried exiting the shell, restarting sshd, and then had to use `eval ssh-agent` to appease the "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." error, but still no success. Any ideas?

`Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (old@example.com)`

Oddly, when I remove the same key it says:

`Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (new@users.noreply.github.com)`

Luckily my GH fetch worked, but still very puzzling. This post says its just stored as comment and not inside the hash: https://serverfault.com/questions/309171/possible-to-change-email-address-in-keypair

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you change the comment via the command below, then you can remove and add it back.

```
$> ssh-keygen -c

Enter file in which the key is (/Users/bob/.ssh/id_rsa): id_ed25519
Enter passphrase:
Old comment: bob@bob.com
New comment: arthur@bob.com
```

then

```
ssh-add -d ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```